# File cracklib_dict.pwd not found when creating a new user or changing his password

Tags: password, dictionary

I have created **new users** and changed his/her password lots of times on Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Desktop, Server, Live... etc.

But, since a few weeks ago (I think it is due to the last system update), I am having **problems at password management** on my Ubuntu Server v14.04.1 LTS (sorry, my Ubuntu is in *spanish*, but I think it is easy to understand the issue):

```
luis@Balanceador:~$ sudo adduser prueba
[sudo] password for luis:
Anadiendo el usuario `prueba' ...
Anadiendo el nuevo grupo `prueba' (1002) ...
Anadiendo el nuevo usuario `prueba' (1002) con grupo `prueba' ...
Creando el directorio personal `/home/prueba' ...
Copiando los ficheros desde `/etc/skel' ...
Nueva contrasena:
/var/cache/cracklib/cracklib_dict.pwd: No existe el archivo o el directorio
BAD PASSWORD: The password fails the dictionary check - error cargando diccionario
Vuelva a escribir la nueva contrasena:
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for prueba
```

The **main problem** translates to: `/var/cache/cracklib/cracklib_dict.pwd: No such file or directory`.

Same behavior for changing passwords:

```
luis@Balanceador:~$ sudo passwd prueba
Nueva contrasena:
/var/cache/cracklib/cracklib_dict.pwd: No existe el archivo o el directorio
BAD PASSWORD: The password fails the dictionary check - error cargando diccionario
Vuelva a escribir la nueva contrasena:
passwd: password updated successfully
```

The password seems to be set OK, but I think it could be good to repair this **bad password verification** system.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Installing the **package crack-lib** solved it for me:

```
sudo apt-get install cracklib-runtime
```

I had it working fine too, but one day (after some update) it disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I already had `cracklib-runtime`, and after trying to install it it said `cracklib-runtime is already the newest version (2.9.6-5build1)`. I retried the command with `--reinstall` and it I was able to successfully set a password. So basically if [@Sopalajo de Arrierez's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/557772/1572484) doesn't work, try this command:

```bash
sudo apt-get install cracklib-runtime --reinstall
```